# Why is my Foreign Key relationship not applying constraint rules?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I'm using a WAMP stack with phpMyAdmin and the db engine is MyISAM. I created two tables: Parent, Child. In the Parent table I set the id column as PK and in the Child table I set the parent_id column as FK. Based on my understanding this relationship will not allow me to add a record to the child table where the value of child.parent_id does not match any value in parent.id.

I then inserted one row of data into the Parent table (thus creating 1 record who's id column = 1). But then I tried to insert a row into the Child table with the parent_id = 2, and it allowed me.

Why?

Snapshot of the table structures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/byAdv.png

Comment: After applying the DB engine change to InnoDB, I'm still allowed to add rows into the child table whose fk does not match any of the parent's PK's.  Confused. *Also can't remove my answer since it was automatically approved as there were no other comments...

Comment: But surprisingly when I created two new tables in the same db, and set their engine to InnoDB from the start, and then attempted to test the same constraint, it did fire correctly. Does this mean that tables that were created using the MyISAM, and then were filled with data, and then had their engine changed to InnoDB, still ignore those constraints?  This is is the behavior I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicions were answered from Quora: MyISAM does not enforce this constraint. Changed to InnoDB.

Comment: Can't remove my answer since it was automatically approved as there were no other comments...